# json data not accessible in html

Tags: angular5

I'm trying to access the JSON data using the following `component.html`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>website</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of users1">
            <td>{{users1.id}}</td>
            <td>{{users1.email}}</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm able to access the string variable correctly in the HTML but i think there is some delay in getting the JSON data.
My `service.ts` looks like this:

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  users: string[] = ['jgfjyghj', 'gjygh'];

  getUser() {
    return this.users[0];
  }

  getUsersJ() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  }
}
```

`component.ts` looks like this:

```
export class ListTasksComponent implements OnInit {
  users1: any;
  user: string;
  constructor(private dataservice: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataservice.getUsersJ().subscribe(data => {
      this.users1 = data;
      console.log(this.users1);
    });
    this.user = this.dataservice.getUser();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `users1` inside your `*ngFor`.

You should use what you defined in the `let` - in this case `d`.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>website</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of users1">
            <td>{{d.id}}</td>
            <td>{{d.email}}</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynsmye)

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let d of users1">
    <td>{{d.id}}</td>
    <td>{{d.email}}</td>

Comment: Can you fork the stackblitz I made and reproduce it there? Because as you can see there, it is working...

Comment: It is working for me too when i have only one component ,but my project has may components and this particular component is part of side-bar ..

Comment: The answer solves the problem you presented in your question. It is impossible to debug your code in the comment section. Especially without a [mcve]. Please edit your question and provide more details.